# why both pdfbox and pdfrenderer can not support "Additional fonts"?

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox, pdfrenderer

I have a pdf which contains 'UniCNS-UCS2-H' font, 
I tried both pdfbox and pdfrenderer, they all throw exception:
Unknown encoding for 'UniCNS-UCS2-H'

and this font was included in a font file :mingliu.ttc(it's a true type collection file, I don't know does this matter ?

what can I do to let these two libraries support additional fonts ?

Comment: i never used pdfbox , but adding new font is easy with iText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding for a font in PDF documents is specified in the font dictionary object. The font you are encountering is encoded using 'UniCNS-UCS2-H', which as far as I can tell is a variant of Chinese encoding.

PDFBox only supports 4 encodings:

1. PDFDocEncoding
2. MacRomanEncoding
3. StandardEncoding
4. WinAnsiEncoding

These are defined in the font dictionary object inside the pdf stream
 (e.g. `.../Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/...`)

When PDFBox encounters an unknown encoding, the exception you reported is shown.

For more information about fonts in PDF documents, see section 9.5 through 9.8 of the [PDF Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)